# TypeError:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I keep getting this error: **TypeError:** *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.*

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import femaleProfile from './images/femaleProfile.jpg';
import maleProfile from './images/maleProfile.jpg';

const Employees = () => {

  const { employees, setEmployees } = useState([{
    id: 1,
    fullName: "Bob Jones",
    designation: "JavaScript Developer",
    gender: "male",
    teamName: "TeamA"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    fullName: "Jill Bailey",
    designation: "Node Developer",
    gender: "female",
    teamName: "TeamA"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    fullName: "Gail Shepherd",
    designation: "Java Developer",
    gender: "female",
    teamName: "TeamA"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    fullName: "Sam Reynolds",
    designation: "React Developer",
    gender: "male",
    teamName: "TeamB"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    fullName: "David Henry",
    designation: "DotNet Developer",
    gender: "male",
    teamName: "TeamB"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    fullName: "Sarah Blake",
    designation: "SQL Server DBA",
    gender: "female",
    teamName: "TeamB"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    fullName: "James Bennet",
    designation: "Angular Developer",
    gender: "male",
    teamName: "TeamC"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    fullName: "Jessica Faye",
    designation: "API Developer",
    gender: "female",
    teamName: "TeamC"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    fullName: "Lita Stone",
    designation: "C++ Developer",
    gender: "female",
    teamName: "TeamC"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    fullName: "Daniel Young",
    designation: "Python Developer",
    gender: "male",
    teamName: "TeamD"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    fullName: "Adrian Jacobs",
    designation: "Vue Developer",
    gender: "male",
    teamName: "TeamD"
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    fullName: "Devin Monroe",
    designation: "Graphic Designer",
    gender: "male",
    teamName: "TeamD"
  }]);


  return (
    <main className='container'>
      <div class='row justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3'>
        <div class='col-8'>
          {
            employees.map((employee) => (
              <div id={employee.id} className='card'>
                <img src={femaleProfile} className='card-img-top' />
                <div className='card-body'>
                  <h5 className='card-title'>Full Name: {employee.fullName}</h5>
                  <p className='card-text'><b>Designation:</b> {employee.designation}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </main >
  )
}

export default Employees
```

I keep getting this error:TypeError:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useState` returns an array, not an object

Use this:

```
const [ employees, setEmployees ] = useState(/* */)
```

not this:

```
const { employees, setEmployees } = useState(/* */)
```